# What Hebrew font should I use for my English sefer?

Tags: jewish-books, writing-printing, torah-writing

I'm writing a sefer on sugyos of the Gemara in English. There is a lot of Hebrew mixed in with the English. The problem with the font(s) I'm using currently (calibri for english, frank ruehl for hebrew) is that the transition from English to Hebrew isn't smooth, it's jarring when the eyes of the reader go from the left-to-right English to the right-to-left Hebrew, and it ruins the immersion.

So, what Hebrew font can you recommend that will have a smoother transition when going from the English to the Hebrew parts of the paragraphs?

Comment: Funnily enough I find that Times New Roman has a pleasant Hebrew font.

Comment: While this may be borderline on topic, I think it should probably still be put on hold as Primarily Opinion Based. I'm not sure there are sufficient objective criteria for evaluating an answer

Comment: If you want smooth transition, consider using either [serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) or sans serif fonts, but don't mix them.

Comment: ...and I hereby use my unbinding 5th vote to do so.